# Edittext without value force closes my App

Tags: android, integer, android-edittext

I am getting a force close when there is Int on my edittext and an OK button is pressed.

05-07 16:00:12.945: E/AndroidRuntime(28366): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Thats the logcat error I am getting.

Here is the code:

```
//Button OK

Button bOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
bOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast invalid = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only values between 0-255 will be accepted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        uin = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());

        if ( uin <= 255 ) {
            Process process = null;
            try {
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            try {
                os.writeBytes("chmod 644 sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness\n");
                os.writeBytes("echo " +uin+ " > sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness\n");
                os.writeBytes("chmod 444 sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness\n");
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if ( uin > 255 ) {
            invalid.show(); 
        }
    }
});
```

How can i tell the app if there is no value input on the `EditText` ( uin missing ) show toast, and not force close? :D

Please be gentle on me, this is my second week with java and android, I have never had any programming language experiences before :)

Comment: what is InputType of Edittext in .xml file? it must be numeric.  try like "android:inputType="number""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the line  uin = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
with a try/catch block like this

```
try {
    uin = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check if your editext is empty if it is then catch exception and if it's not proceed to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should catch the exception that is thrown:

```
try {
    uin = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    //What to do if the exception is thrown...
    [... Your code ...] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set your Edittext in .xml

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and try to enclose with Try-catch block like

```
try {
    uin = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());   
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

using `e.printStackTrace();` u can find which Exception occur at this stage.

Comment: Wow you guys were amazingly fast! Thanks A LOT people :)